# Understanding what "dp" works on different screen dimensions

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Imagine that I have a .png file with dimensions of 1280x1550px and I make a .xml file with that .png with the following characteristics:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="21dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/pngfile"
        />
```

Imagine that I launch the app on an android device with 1080x1920 dimension and later I launch the app on another device with 1440x2560. What will be the size of this UI? Will these 21dp of width and height adapt to different screen sizes? I mean if the screen size is bigger this xml file will be bigger and if the screen size is smaller it will be smaller adapting to all screen sizes?Or it will have an independent size for all screen dimensions?

Answer (score 2):

> Imagine that I launch the app on an android device with 1080x1920 dimension

1080x1920 is a resolution, not a dimension.

> What will be the size of this UI?

It will be `21dp` by `21dp`. Since 1 dp is 1/160 of an inch, it will be 21/160  inches = 0.13125 inches on a side.

> Will these 21dp of width and height adapt to different screen sizes?

No. `dp` units adapt for screen *density*, not *resolution*.

> I mean if the screen size is bigger this xml file will be bigger and if the screen size is smaller it will be smaller adapting to all screen sizes?

No.

> Or it will have an independent size for all screen dimensions?

It will have an independent size for all screen *resolutions*.

Comment: Is the awnser to "I mean if the screen size is bigger this xml file will be bigger and if the screen size is smaller it will be smaller adapting to all screen sizes?" really NO? I mean, okay it will adapt to screen density, so if a device has a bigger resolution it has a bigger density so the UI will be bigger on a bigger screen than on an smaller screen. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Tanque: That depends on what you mean by "a bigger screen". My interpretation of that phrase is tied to physical size. Resolution is not tied strictly tied to physical size. You seem to interpret "a bigger resolution" and "a bigger screen" as being equivalent, and I disagree with that interpretation.

Comment: Yes, I was interpreting like that. I thought that if the resolution of a device increases the size of the screen increases. Okay, so imagine this other example. The first device is 5 inches and another device is 6.3 inches. Will the UI with the 21dp of width and 21dp of height of the example of the question be bigger in the device of 6.3inches that in the device of 5 inches?

Comment: "I thought that if the resolution of a device increases the size of the screen increases" -- within arm's reach of me I have a 1920x1080 5-inch phone and a 1920x1080 23-inch monitor. "Will the UI with the 21dp of width and 21dp of height of the example of the question be bigger in the device of 6.3inches that in the device of 5 inches?" -- we have no way of knowing. `dp` takes screen *density* into account, and you have not stated the density of either of those devices.

Comment: Okay I am starting to understand that dp depends on the density of each device. I don´t understand when the density is bigger or smaller. I mean, I have just searched on Google and it showed up this: "Pixel density is a data calculated based on the resolution and size of the screen that allows us to know the number of pixels that a smartphone is capable of displaying in one inch". So here it says that density depends on the screen size, so if it the screen size is bigger, won´t the density be bigger?

Comment: "So here it says that density depends on the screen size, so if it is bigger the density won´t be bigger?" -- no. If the resolution stays constant, bigger physical size means lower density. The density of a 23-inch 1920x1080 monitor is much lower than is the density of a 5-inch 1920x1080 phone. There are many more pixels ("dots") per inch on the phone.

Comment: Okay, so if dp is not a good solution to adapt the UI to every screen size, how can I do it? I want to adapt the UI so that if the device is bigger the UI also is bigger. Imagine that the devise is superbig, the UI would be very small if the UI does not adapt to the screen size. Could you help me to make UI adaptable please?

Comment: There is documentation on that subject, such as [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes) and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support) and [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive).

Comment: Thanks, I have found this and I think this is the solution, do you think so?                                                   res/
      drawable-xxxhdpi/
        awesome-image.png
      drawable-xxhdpi/
        awesome-image.png
      drawable-xhdpi/
        awesome-image.png
      drawable-hdpi/
        awesome-image.png
      drawable-mdpi/
        awesome-image.png

Comment: Using density buckets like `xhdpi` for drawable resources scales those images based upon changes in screen *density*. They are unrelated to screen *size*.

Comment: I have been looking for an hour for a solution and I have not find it. Could you at least tell me what should i look for? Thanks

Comment: I provided you with three links to documentation earlier in this comment thread. There is no "do this one thing" solution. Even within the narrow range of phones to tablets, there are many different approaches -- the way that you scale up a video player is different than how you scale up a social media client, which is different than how you scale up a photo gallery, etc. By the time you get to extremes in sizes (watches and TVs), you need a completely different user interface.